# Why did the function key shortcuts in Pages, for text paragraph styles, just completely stopped working on in macOS?

Tags: pages, bug

On every single Mac I have (whether 2015 MBP with 12.6.1, or brand new latest Macs w/ Ventura),

The <kbd>fn</kbd> key shortcuts, for text styles, no longer works in Pages.

What could this possibly be?

When you click one of the <kbd>fn</kbd> keys, it simply "beeps" and nothing happens.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

To test, open Pages and try a function key in any Pages doc.

[image]

## Update - fixed?

I recently bought a

- M2 2022 MacBookAir
- Currently with Ventura 13.0.1
- The latest Pages (actually 12.0 7033.0.134)

Fortunately they do seem to have resolved the problem, it now works normally.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work around, first select the text you want to style, then press the shortcut key combo. I've filed a bug, because this regression does not exist in Numbers 12.2

Comment: Happy to note that this issue has been resolved in Pages 12.2.1 which has been very recently released: no need to select some text first to apply a paragraph style through a function key shortcut. Thank you to everyone who reported this to Apple.

Comment: Right on @Alper. - it's fixed!  hooray

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph style keyboard shortcuts feature [still exists and works](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/use-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-apply-a-text-style-tanb8c18c476/12.2/mac/1.0) according to Apple's [Pages support document](https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/welcome/12.2/mac) which mentions v12.2 in its main page.

The feature not working is most probably a bug that came with Pages v12.2 rather than macOS Ventura. I did not have this problem with Pages v12.1 that came out in June 2022. A few days ago, I have upgraded Pages to v12.2 and started experiencing the same problem on macOS 12.6.1.

I am not sure if the bug can be circumvented by any means. Perhaps, the best course of action for now is to report it to Apple via the [Apple Pages feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html) webpage so that they issue a fix ASAP.

Comment: Thank you so much for this report!  I can confirm absolutely that the hardware makes no difference, and the Mac OS makes no difference. It is a pure Pages problem.